# Entity framework code first, shopping cart

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework, I was trying to implement a simple shopping cart using code first approach, and I didnt understand why entity generates the table in strange way below. Here is the cut down version of my classes:

Product.cs

```
public class Product 
{
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; } 
public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; } 
public string ProductNumber { get; set; } 
public string Name { get; set; } 
public string Description { get; set; } 
public string Specification { get; set; } 
public string Color { get; set; } 
public string Capacity { get; set; } 
public string CapacityUnitMeasureCode { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
public int Stock { get; set; } 
}
```

ShoppingCart.cs

```
public class ShoppingCart
{ 
    [Key] 
    [Column (Order=1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } 

    public virtual List<Product> products { get; set; } 
}
```

Because of this line
    public virtual List products { get; set; } 
Entity generates the Product table with 2 additional foreign keys:
ShoppingCart_ID & ShoppingCart_ProductID

Which I dont understand. my intention was to create a List of product that associated to a particular shopping cart. What I am I doing wrong. Could someone shed some light please!

Comment: First, this line "public int ProductID {get; set;}" shouldn't be in ShoppingCart class definition. Remove it to see what happens.
Second, I would expect an extra table to keep the relationship between shoppingcart and its related products.

Comment: This seems to solve my issue. replace the "public virtual List<Product> products { get; set; }" with "public virtual Product Product { get; set; }", that seems to correct FK constraint on the ProductID. while not adding additional keys on the Product table. - Thanks Guys

Comment: I think although this solve your issue, it won't be the design you want. Because one shoppingcart may contains multiple products. And one product can be in different shopping cards, it's a many-to-many relationship. You need an extra table to reflect the relationship

Comment: @Eric. Actually it should work, as you see ShoppingCart class has a compound PK(ID,ProductID),  while ID is CardID and also a FK for customer table. so yes is not complete normalized but since shopping cart item comes and goes (when order submitted). so I don't think it is an issue. - Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

SInce you have ProductID as one of the property in shopping cart class and you have virtual product collection in shopping cart, EF has established relationship between shopping cart and product class.

as suggested in comment you can remove product id class or you can create a view model class and establish relation ship between shopping cart and product class.

Sample View model can be

```
public class ShoppingCartProduct
{ 
    [Key] 
    [Column (Order=1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
}
```

you can read about view model here

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frachelappel.com%2Fuse-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications&ei=EP20VNqDHcTkuQTqvYGoAw&usg=AFQjCNHdOjOFhZGuBiLHZJ0wBGsG9qQtXw&sig2=rSFNWzWstWP0z0yRDhuXXQ

Answer (score 0):

The great solution for you is to make a class `ShopingCart` wich contain all your products and their number:

```
[Table("Cart")]
public class ShopingCart
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<ItemCart> Products { get; set; } // relationship one-to-many
}
```

And the class wich contains your `ItemCart`

```
[Table("ItemCart")]
public class ItemCart
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; } 

   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public virtual Product Product { get; set; } // relationship one-to-one
}
```

If you want to learn more look on this page: [entity-tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

And try to make think simple: You have just 3 possible relationships:

1. one-to-one
2. one-to-many
3. many-to-many but here is creating an intermittent table [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-o0d_e9mW8)

Hope to be useful for you!